# how to save in output the produce output with format FIRSTNAME LASTNAME and output is LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME

Tags: regex, perl

My output does not save into hi.txt

```
open(my $fh, '>', 'C:\Users\yukari\Desktop\hi.txt');

$x = <STDIN>;
if ($x =~ /(.+) (.+)/) 
{
  print " $2 ,";
  print " $1\n";

  print $fh = "$2, $1 \n" ;
  close $fh;
}
```

Comment: I'll say this just in case: `.+` is greedy and the first one will consume the whole string up to the very last space.  Is that intended?

Comment: I've added indentation to your code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future.

Comment: Why do you only close the file if the regex matches?

Answer (score -2):

Can you recollect the coding, couple of issues you can arrest nicely

```
open(my $fh, '>', "hi.txt");
$x = <STDIN>;

#1. You should do the chomp whenever getting the values from user
chomp($x);

if ($x =~ /(.+) (.+)/) 
{
    print " $2 ,";
    print " $1\n";

    #2. No need to store the variable in the FILEHANDLE
    print $fh "$2, $1 \n" ;
    close $fh;
}
```

Thanks.